# How to call workbook in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook I'm writing a macro for, and I would like the data to be saved cumulatively in another workbook. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
Sub Copy_Data()
Dim LastRow As Variant
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("I:\Business Administration\Warehouse-Logistics\NFI Trucks\Dedicated Truck Database.xlsm")

LastRow = Worksheets("MorningReport").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Worksheets("MorningReport").Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("MERRMorningReport").Range("B1").Value
End Sub
```

I got the part that references a different workbook from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801598/how-do-i-reference-to-another-open-or-closed-workbook-and-pull-values-back-). What I'm wondering is, now that I've dim'd the workbook as wbk, what notation is required to put into my code to reference the worksheet "MorningReport". That is the worksheet in the other workbook I'm trying to get the cell to save to. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: `wbk.Worksheets("MorningReport")` and `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MERRMorningReport")` or vice versa

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thank you!!!!!