# Excel VBA to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel document with 3 tabs (Report, MI & CSR Data Dump).

When the report tab is complete and "submit" button pushed. The current VBA writes to the data dump sheet perfectly.

However I want to move the data dump into a separate workbook. I have tried and failed. Location:- K:\Call Quality\Quality MI\Quality MI.XLSM This will be the same worksheet name "Data Dump"

My current VBA which works perfectly is

```
Private Sub generate_report()

Dim i As Long
Dim fullcount As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Worksheets("CSR Data Dump")

With ws

fullcount = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
i = fullcount + 1


    Range("XER2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("a" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("XER5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("b" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("XER3:xer4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("c" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

     Range("XER6:xer7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("e" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("d11:d17").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("g" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("d19").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("o" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("e19:e22").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("s" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("d23").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("w" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("e23:e28").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("aa" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("d29").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("ag" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("e29:e33").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("ak" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("d34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("ap" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("e34:e37").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("at" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("d38").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("ax" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("e38:e39").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("az" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("d40").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("bb" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("E40:E42").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("Be" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("d44").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("bh" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("E44:e46").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("Bk" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("d47").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("bn" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("E47:e54").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("Bv" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("d55").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("cd" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("E55:e56").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("ch" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("d58").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("cl" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("E60:e63").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("cp" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("h65:h67").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("ct" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("j11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("cw" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("j19").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("cx" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("j44").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("cy" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("j60").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("cz" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select

    Range("j65").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    Range("da" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("j64").Select


End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to `ws`, but then you are not using this `With` reference anywhere. You have to refer to it with a point, like this:

```
With ws

fullcount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
i = fullcount + 1


    .Range("XER2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    .Sheets("CSR Data dump").Select
    .Range("a" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    .Sheets("CM Form").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Concerning the `ws`, if it stays in another workbook, then it should be refered like this:

```
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("K:\Call Quality\Quality MI\Quality MI.XLSM")
Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("CSR Data dump")
```

[How do I reference to another (open or closed) workbook, and pull values back, in VBA? - Excel 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801598/how-do-i-reference-to-another-open-or-closed-workbook-and-pull-values-back-i)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but editing this does not resolve my problem of being unable to write the data into another workbook.

My VBA example above works perfectly however it write to the same workbook. I would like it to write to another workbook.

Comment: @DarrenStenson - you have to refer to the other workbook in a proper way - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801598/how-do-i-reference-to-another-open-or-closed-workbook-and-pull-values-back-i

Comment: @DarrenStenson FYI you don't have to make so many selections to copy and paste values to/from worksheets/workbooks all you have to do is set them equal to each other like `Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:H3").Value = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:H3").Value` as an example.  This will speed up your code significantly.

Answer (score 0):

The below should take care of pasting into a different workbook

```
Private Sub generate_report()

Dim i As Long
Dim fullcount As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wbk as Workbook
Dim srcWbk as Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set srcWbk = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("K:\Call Quality\Quality MI\Quality MI.XLSM")
Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("CSR Data dump")
srcWbk.Activate
'You are not using With appropriately so let's drop this till you learn how to use it.
'With ws

fullcount = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A"))
i = fullcount + 1

    'Do this only once
    Sheets("CM Form").Select    
    ws.Range("a" & i).Value=Range("XER2").Value

    ws.Range("b" & i).Value=Range("XER5").Value

    ws.Range("c" & i & ":c" & (i+1)).Value=Range("XER3:xer4").Value

    ws.Range("e" & i & ":e" & (i+1)).Value=Range("XER6:xer7").Value

    ws.Range("g" & i & ":g" & (i+6)).Value=Range("d11:d17").Value

    ws.Range("o" & i).Value=Range("d19").Value

    ws.Range("s" & i & ":s" & (i+3)).Value=Range("e19:e22").Value

    ws.Range("w" & i).Value=Range("d23").Value

    ws.Range("aa" & i & ":aa" & (i+5)).Value=Range("e23:e28").Value

    ws.Range("ag" & i).Value=Range("d29").Value

    ws.Range("ak" & i & ":ak" & (i+4)).Value=Range("e29:e33").Value

    ws.Range("ap" & i).Value=Range("d34").Value

    ws.Range("at" & i & ":at" & (i+3)).Value=Range("e34:e37").Value

    ws.Range("ax" & i).Value=Range("d38").Value

    ws.Range("az" & i & ":az" & (i+1)).Value=Range("e38:e39").Value

    ws.Range("bb" & i).Value=Range("d40").Value

    ws.Range("Be" & i & ":be" & (i+2)).Value=Range("E40:E42").Value

    ws.Range("bh" & i).Value=Range("d44").Value

    ws.Range("Bk" & i & ":bk" & (i+2)).Value=Range("E44:e46").Value

    ws.Range("bn" & i).Value=Range("d47").Value

    ws.Range("Bv" & i & ":bv" & (i+7)).Value=Range("E47:e54").Value

    ws.Range("cd" & i).Value=Range("d55").Value

    ws.Range("ch" & i & ":ch" & (i+1)).Value=Range("E55:e56").Value

    ws.Range("cl" & i).Value=Range("d58").Value

    ws.Range("cp" & i & ":cp" & (i+3)).Value=Range("E60:e63").Value

    ws.Range("ct" & i & ":ct" & (i+2)).Value=Range("h65:h67").Value

    ws.Range("cw" & i).Value=Range("j11").Value

    ws.Range("cx" & i).Value=Range("j19").Value

    ws.Range("cy" & i).Value=Range("j44").Value

    ws.Range("cz" & i).Value=Range("j60").Value

    ws.Range("da" & i).Value=Range("j65").Value
'End With 

'Save and close the target workbook
wbk.Close(True)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Below is completely your choice, and just a suggestion
I will keep the whole function as is(With only changes at start of Sub to `fullcount=` statement as shown) and change the signature of the Sub as below

```
Private Sub generate_report(ws As Worksheet)

Dim i As Long
Dim fullcount As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
.
.
.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This allows you to paste the data into any target sheet that you pass in. It could be in the same workbook or a different workbook. And I would call it as below

```
Dim wbk as Workbook
Dim srcWbk as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set srcWbk = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("K:\Call Quality\Quality MI\Quality MI.XLSM")
Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("CSR Data dump")
srcWbk.Activate
Call generate_report(ws)
wbk.Close(True)
```

**OR**

```
Dim srcWbk as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CSR Data dump")
Call generate_report(ws)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @r.roe, I've incorporated your advice into my answer.

Comment: @DarrenStenson apologies for so many edits but this should be good.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried copying and pasting your first code and I get an error message.
"Compile error: Invalid or unqualified refrence". 
I have also tried adding in the other code and still getting an error.

Comment: There was a small typo that I corrected. From `fullcount = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))` to `fullcount = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A"))`

Comment: Thank you! Its now copying to the workbook which is GREAT however, its not keeping the same format as my original VBA. For example some information is going vertically 3 or 4 cells the continuing horizontally.

Comment: @TeKaZi in your original code you've not copied the formats if you you have done only `Paste:=xlPasteValues`. So I kept the same functionality as is without copying formats. Can you elaborate on  `some information is going vertically 3 or 4 cells the continuing horizontally.`? Columns  C/E/G/S/AA/AK/AT/AZ/BE/BK/BV/CH/CP/CT will have more than one value in them. BV will have 8 values in it's column(vertically)